# In ansible, how to synchronize 2 folders on the same remote machine?

Tags: rsync, ansible, ansible-2.x

I have the following simple task:

copying everything in folder A to folder B. Since I have many hosts in a group, I use the following yaml task definition:

```
- name: Sync /etc/spark/conf to $SPARK_HOME/conf
  synchronize: src=/etc/spark/conf dest={{spark_home}}/conf
  delegate_to: "{{item}}"
  with_items: "{{play_hosts}}"
  tags: spark
```

However, running ansible-playbook gave me the following error:

```
TASK [cloudera : Sync /etc/spark/conf to $SPARK_HOME/conf] *********************
failed: [52.53.220.119 -> 52.53.200.0] (item=52.53.200.0) => {"cmd": "/usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsh 'ssh -i /home/peng/.ssh/saphana.pem -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' --rsync-path=\"sudo rsync\" --out-format='<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L' \"/etc/spark/conf\" \"52.53.220.119:/opt/spark/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.4/conf\"", "failed": true, "item": "52.53.200.0", "msg": "Warning: Identity file /home/peng/.ssh/saphana.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.\nPermission denied (publickey).\r\nrsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]\nrsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.0]\n", "rc": 255}
failed: [52.53.200.193 -> 52.53.200.0] (item=52.53.200.0) => {"cmd": "/usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsh 'ssh -i /home/peng/.ssh/saphana.pem -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' --rsync-path=\"sudo rsync\" --out-format='<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L' \"/etc/spark/conf\" \"52.53.200.193:/opt/spark/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.4/conf\"", "failed": true, "item": "52.53.200.0", "msg": "Warning: Identity file /home/peng/.ssh/saphana.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.\nPermission denied (publickey).\r\nrsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]\nrsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.0]\n", "rc": 255}
ok: [52.53.200.0 -> 52.53.200.0] => (item=52.53.200.0)
ok: [52.53.220.119 -> 52.53.220.119] => (item=52.53.220.119)
failed: [52.53.200.193 -> 52.53.220.119] (item=52.53.220.119) => {"cmd": "/usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsh 'ssh -i /home/peng/.ssh/saphana.pem -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' --rsync-path=\"sudo rsync\" --out-format='<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L' \"/etc/spark/conf\" \"52.53.200.193:/opt/spark/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.4/conf\"", "failed": true, "item": "52.53.220.119", "msg": "Warning: Identity file /home/peng/.ssh/saphana.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.\nPermission denied (publickey).\r\nrsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]\nrsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.0]\n", "rc": 255}
failed: [52.53.200.0 -> 52.53.220.119] (item=52.53.220.119) => {"cmd": "/usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsh 'ssh -i /home/peng/.ssh/saphana.pem -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' --rsync-path=\"sudo rsync\" --out-format='<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L' \"/etc/spark/conf\" \"52.53.200.0:/opt/spark/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.4/conf\"", "failed": true, "item": "52.53.220.119", "msg": "Warning: Identity file /home/peng/.ssh/saphana.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.\nPermission denied (publickey).\r\nrsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]\nrsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.0]\n", "rc": 255}
ok: [52.53.200.193 -> 52.53.200.193] => (item=52.53.200.193)
failed: [52.53.220.119 -> 52.53.200.193] (item=52.53.200.193) => {"cmd": "/usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsh 'ssh -i /home/peng/.ssh/saphana.pem -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' --rsync-path=\"sudo rsync\" --out-format='<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L' \"/etc/spark/conf\" \"52.53.220.119:/opt/spark/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.4/conf\"", "failed": true, "item": "52.53.200.193", "msg": "Warning: Identity file /home/peng/.ssh/saphana.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.\nPermission denied (publickey).\r\nrsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]\nrsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.0]\n", "rc": 12}
failed: [52.53.200.0 -> 52.53.200.193] (item=52.53.200.193) => {"cmd": "/usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsh 'ssh -i /home/peng/.ssh/saphana.pem -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' --rsync-path=\"sudo rsync\" --out-format='<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L' \"/etc/spark/conf\" \"52.53.200.0:/opt/spark/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.4/conf\"", "failed": true, "item": "52.53.200.193", "msg": "Warning: Identity file /home/peng/.ssh/saphana.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.\nPermission denied (publickey).\r\nrsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]\nrsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.0]\n", "rc": 255}
```

Apparently, it looks like ansible is trying to create permutative pairs between all of my 3 hosts and synchronize between every pairs (so 9 rsync is performed), how do I avoid this and command ansible to only conduct rsync locally?

**UPDATE**: I've changed my task definition to use delegate.host:

```
- name: Sync /etc/spark/conf to $SPARK_HOME/conf
  synchronize: src=/etc/spark/conf dest={{spark_home}}/conf
  delegate_to: delegate.host
  tags: spark
```

But it is clearly not interpreted correctly by the ansible engine, the debugging log reveals that it is not substituted by the host IP address:

> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: **None**
>
> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -q -o ControlMaster=auto -o
>   ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o
>   PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey
>   -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/peng/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r
>   **delegate.host** '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "`echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1470667606.38-157157938048153`" &&
>   echo ansible-tmp-1470667606.38-157157938048153="`echo
>   $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1470667606.38-157157938048153`" ) &&
>   sleep 0'"'"''

This looks like a deprecated feature, I'm using ansible 2.1.0.0

Comment: It looks like you need to replace `delegate.host` with real hostname or IP address. I have no idea at this moment, why it worked in my case, but it clearly is connected to `scp_if_ssh = True` setting in `ansible.cfg` without it I get an error too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved:

```yaml
- name: Sync /etc/spark/conf to $SPARK_HOME/conf
  synchronize: 
    src: /etc/spark/conf 
    dest: "{{spark_home}}"
    copy_links: true
  delegate_to: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
  tags: spark
```

The `delegate.host` is probably removed in favour of the new variable.

Comment: No, the `delegate.host` is just a string in the documentation akin to `put.your.host.name.here`. With `scp_if_ssh` flag set whatever I put there was running on exactly one target host.

Comment: I see, so its not a variable in the first place. That's why you deleted your first answer. I believe the documentation should be more clear about it

Comment: @tribbloid : "{{ inventory_hostname }}" is what exactly ; is it the address of the server , or itis a group defined in yur host file?

Comment: @firasKoubaa It's the hostname of the current host that the play is running on, based on its name in the inventory. This makes the src and dest systems one and the same. ansible_fqdn is a good alternative if you specifically need a fully qualified domain name.